# Removing username from UserCreationForm and auto generating username for user based on email, first name and last name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to auto generate username for users as they sign up, however, I do not know where to set the username. I do not want to user signals, so therefore I want to set the username for users when the user signs up.

In my `UserCreationForm` I have remove the username by:

`users = None`

and inside the `SingUpForm(UserCreationForm)` method I have:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
        )
```

However, I do not know how to set the username for the user, should I set the username for user inside the signup view?

```
 user = form.save(commit=False)
 user.username = generate_username(user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email)
 user.save()

Or should I have the generate_username() method inside my custom creation form?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or should I have the generate_username() method inside my custom creation form?

That is probably more appropriate, since the form normally should be responsible to create a valid `User`object, you thus an override the `def save` method:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.cleaned_data
        self.instance.username = generate_username(
            user['first_name'],
            user['last_name'],
            user['email']
        )
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

then in the view, it is simply:

```
user = form.save()
```